# How can I show the free abelian group of rank $r$ is isomorphic to an $r$-copy of $\mathbb{Z}_\infty$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups

Today, this problem was given to me.

> Let $F$ be a abelian free group of rank $r$. Show that it is isomorphic to an $r$-copy of $Z_{\infty}$.

I could do some messy job about it but so far I failed to solve it.  The time for solving it in time is over, but please help me solve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly is Z_\infty ?

Comment: @IttayWeiss: I had the same problem. Anyway, I assumed it is $\mathbb Z$

Comment: then now the question is, what is your definition for a free group of rank r?

Comment: That is: there is a set $X$ of dimension r and $X$ can generate $F$.

Comment: Certainly if $F$ is finite it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^r$. There is a trivial homomorphism in the other direction though.

Comment: that can't be right since then any finite group G is free of rank |G|. Somehow the freeness has to be taken into account in the definition.

Comment: You cannot expect to solve a problem if you do not know the definitions of the words in the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you mean to say a *free abelian group* of rank $r$.  The definition of a free abelian group $\mathfrak{F}$ of rank $r$ is a group with a generating set $\mathfrak{S}$ of size $r$ for which the only relation is that $[s,t]=1$ for each $s,t\in \mathfrak{S}$.  Note that free abelian groups are not free groups when $r\geq 2$.

Once we have this definition digested, the path to victory is quite clear.  Let $\epsilon_i$ denote the generator of the $i^{\rm th}$ $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{r}$.  Number the generators in $\mathfrak{S}$ as $s_1,\ldots,s_r$.  Define $\Phi:\mathfrak{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^r$ by $\Phi:s_i\rightarrow \epsilon_i$. Now, can you prove that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism?

> We have the relations that $[s_i,s_j]=1$ for each $i,j$. Given an arbitrary word $w=s_{i_1}^{e_1}s_{i_2}^{e_2}\cdots s_{i_s}^{e_s}$ (with $i_1,\ldots,i_s$ not necessarily distinct) can you rewrite $w$ in the form $s_1^{f_1}\cdots s_r^{f_r}$?  Where does $\Phi$ send that in $\mathbb{Z}^r$?  Finally, can you prove that $\Phi$ is bijective using the fact there are no other relations on $\mathfrak{F}$?

Comment: "The only relation is" is too hand-wavy for my taste. I prefer the universal property.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What's hand-wavy about it?  The free abelian group of rank $r$ is the quotient of the free group on a set $\mathfrak{S}$ of $r$ generators by the normal subgroup generated by $\{[x,y]:x,y\in \mathfrak{S}\}$.